# SQL Geography Datatype , checking Point in Polygon , STIntersects producing wrong result

Tags: sql-server, polygon, spatial, point, sqlgeography

I am trying to check point in polygon, but STIntersect producing wrong result, below is given both point and polygon.

```
DECLARE @point GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(25.631119, 54.666181, 4326)

DECLARE @polygon GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POLYGON 
((55.368827104612151 25.270499845366924, 55.368226289792808 
25.268578811810126, 55.367410898252288 25.269529630198974, 
55.368054628415855 25.270364015710307, 55.368827104612151 
25.270499845366924))', 4326)

SELECT @polygon.STIntersects(@point), @point.STIntersects(@polygon)
```

Result is returning 1, however it should return 0, because i pick the point out side of fence,,

Am I making anything wrong with polygon coordinates? Please advice me for any stupid mistake of mine as I am new in spatial data types.

Comment: I've not looked at your data in detail but whenever this sort of question is asked, it's almost certainly because you've got your polygon the wrong way around. I.e. on a sphere a polygon doesn't have an "inside" and an "outside" - it splits the sphere into two regions, *either* of which may be considered to be the inside or the outside. Is a ring around the equator enclosing the northern hemisphere or the south? To fix that, you need to obey the "left hand rule" when defining your polygon.

Comment: It seems that there are some issues in defining points of polygon, i see that sql server follow left hand rule for polygon. But i am providing interface to my users on website where they can define polygon via leafletJS draw. How can i force users to follow Left to right rule?. Is there any way

Comment: Quick help will be appreciated as i m stuck and i do not know how to move on.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to "fix" this, we need to make *some* form of assumption. If the assumption cannot be "instruct the users to enter polygons that obey the left-hand rule" then we have to use something else.

Here, I'm assuming that the correct "sense" for the polygon is whichever way around means that it's enclosing the smallest area:

```
DECLARE @point GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(25.631119, 54.666181, 4326)

DECLARE @polygon GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POLYGON 
((55.368827104612151 25.270499845366924,
55.368226289792808 25.268578811810126,
55.367410898252288 25.269529630198974, 
55.368054628415855 25.270364015710307,
55.368827104612151 25.270499845366924))', 4326)

SET @polygon = CASE
    WHEN @polygon.STArea() > @polygon.ReorientObject().STArea()
        THEN @polygon.ReorientObject()
    ELSE @polygon
    END

SELECT @polygon
```

(You may also wish to do a plain `SELECT @polygon` before the `CASE` to see what the original looked like)

However, take careful note of what the above assumption means - if your users may wish to provide "the whole planet minus this small area around 55 degrees East/25 degrees North", there's now no way for you to accept such a value.

---

References - [`STArea`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/starea-geography-data-type) [`ReorientObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/reorientobject-geography-data-type)

Comment: I like to use `@polygon.EnvelopeAngle()` as my heuristic, but anything you do is going to have the issues that you've described.